# issue on running Hikari connection pooling in server

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am trying to implement Hikari connection pooling with JAVA 7, spring and Hibernate 5 project. I am getting the below error message continuously on running the code.

Added following code for Hikari set up in addition to already running Spring with hibernate project.

Build.gradle

```
compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-hikaricp:5.2.10.Final")
compile("com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java7:2.4.12")
```

DatabaseConfig.java

```
 final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
      ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
      ds.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
      ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
      ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
      return ds;
```

Application.properties

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class=com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider
```

After adding this project I am getting the below expception on running

> org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider:
>   Provider
>   org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.StrategyRegistrationProviderImpl not
>   found

Please let me know if you know the Answer.

Comment: show some code. How you have configured hikaricp?

Comment: @SangamBelose Edited the question with few codes which I added for configuring HikariCP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot then the property should be like this:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_class=com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider`

More reading: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html